# How do I move the IconButton to the right side of the Tab?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have this appBar with a tab and an IconButton. I wanted to put the IconButton at the right side, but `float: right` does not work.

This is what it looks like:
[image]

I have also recreated this in code sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-morning-6pf26?file=/src/App.js:234-2709

Below are the entire codes:

```
export default function App() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const isMenuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);

  const handleProfileMenuOpen = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleMenuClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const menuId = "primary-search-account-menu";
  const renderMenu = (
    <Menu
      anchorEl={anchorEl}
      anchorOrigin={{ vertical: "top", horizontal: "right" }}
      id={menuId}
      keepMounted
      transformOrigin={{ vertical: "top", horizontal: "right" }}
      open={isMenuOpen}
      onClose={handleMenuClose}
    >
      <MenuItem>Profile</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem>Log Out</MenuItem>
    </Menu>
  );

  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AppBar
        style={{
          position: "sticky",
          top: "0"
        }}
      >
        <Toolbar variant="dense">
          <div>
            <>
              <Grid
                container
                direction="row"
                justifyContent="space-between"
                alignItems="center"
              >
                <Grid item>
                  <Tabs
                    centered
                    value={value}
                    fullWidth={true}
                    indicatorColor="primary"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    aria-label="simple tabs example"
                    variant="fullWidth"
                  >
                    <Tab disableRipple label="Homepage" to="/" />

                    <Tab disableRipple label="About" to="/about" />

                    <Tab disableRipple label="Admin" to="/admin" />
                  </Tabs>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item alignItems="flex-end" style={{ float: "right" }}>
                  <IconButton
                    edge="end"
                    right
                    aria-label="account of current user"
                    aria-controls={menuId}
                    aria-haspopup="true"
                    onClick={handleProfileMenuOpen}
                    color="inherit"
                  >
                    <AccountCircle />
                  </IconButton>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </>
          </div>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      {renderMenu}
    </div>
  );
}
```

How should I love the AccountCircle at the right edge of the screen?

Comment: You need the `div` spanning the entire toolbar, use `style={width: 100%}`. If possible, also remove the `<>` under the `div` as if it may impact the parent style (`div`)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your snippet in the sandbox is working correctly. Can you double-check that there are no differences between the sandbox and your actual local code?

Looking at your code snippet, it looks like "float: right" is passed to the parent of IconButton, instead of iconbutton itself. Is it fixed (on your local environment, since code snippet appears to work) when you move the style to icon button?

Comment: yes, it was solved. I followed the user's comment from above with `div style`